# Model to link similar data together

Tags: database-design

I am importing issue tickets from a reporting tool into another one. I want to be able to report on the differences between the original tickets and the imported ones once work has been done on them. The tickets have been normalized to have the same attributes on both sides, so the only difference between an original ticket and its import before work has been done is the id, which is the one it has in the corresponding tool. I was wondering what the best model would be to represent this.

Right now i'm thinking about doing one table for each tool, and having another table to link the ids from both tables, but i feel like this would be better suited for one to many or many to many relationships than for one to one.

I thought about having only one table and adding one column to give the linked id, but then i don't know how i can find out if the issue came from one tool or the other. I could add a column "type", but i don't know how good this would be.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a bridge table like this;

This Application ID | Source Application | Source Application ID

Comment: I don't get what "Source Application" stands for in the context of a table. Do you mean i should make two tables and link them using this bridge table, which contain 3 columns ?

Comment: You would need 2 tables, 1 for your Tickets that you pulled in, and then this new table, which links each Id in that table to where it came from (source) by system and the Id in that system